# Updating record rails 4 No route matches [PATCH] "/admin/usersupdate"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this controller

```
 def usersedit
   @user = User.find_by id: params[:id]
 end

 def usersupdate
   @user = User.find_by id: params[:id]
   if @user.update(post_params)
     redirect_to action: :users
   else
     render 'usersedit'
   end
 end
```

And this form in the view in usersedit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :user, url: {action: "usersupdate"}, method: :patch do |f| %>
```

but when I submit the form this error appears

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/admin/usersupdate"
```

My routes code is:

```
     Prefix Verb URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
             root GET  /                               pages#home
      admin_index GET  /admin/index(.:format)          admin#index
     admin_grades GET  /admin/grades(.:format)         admin#grades
       pages_home GET  /pages/home(.:format)           pages#home
   pages_register GET  /pages/register(.:format)       pages#register
     pages_create POST /pages/create(.:format)         pages#create
      pages_login GET  /pages/login(.:format)          pages#login
    pages_logging POST /pages/logging(.:format)        pages#logging
     pages_logout GET  /pages/logout(.:format)         pages#logout
                  GET  /activate/:user/:hash(.:format) pages#activate
         remember POST /remember(.:format)             pages#remember
     reactivation POST /reactivation(.:format)         pages#reactivation
  admin_documents GET  /admin/documents(.:format)      admin#documents
      admin_users GET  /admin/users(.:format)          admin#users
                  GET  /admin/usersedit/:id(.:format)  admin#usersedit
admin_usersupdate POST /admin/usersupdate(.:format)    admin#usersupdate
```

Help please.

Comment: `patch` is not `post`. And why are you not just using resourceful routing?

Answer (score 15):

change the method in the form method: :post

your header of form

```
form_for :user, url: {action: "usersupdate"}, :method => :POST do |f|
```

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, you'll need to update your routes.rb file correctly.

I'm guessing the line in your routes file where you've defined this path starts with "post", try changing that to "patch".

Inside of *config/routes.rb*

**change:**

```
post "admin/usersupdate" => "admin#usersupdate", :as => "admin/usersupdate"
```

**to:**

```
patch "admin/usersupdate" => "admin#usersupdate", :as => "admin/usersupdate"
```

Everything works swimmingly for me after I made this change.

Comment: this solution is easy and forward-thinking, as patch is coming into style: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/2/26/edge-rails-patch-is-the-new-primary-http-method-for-updates/

Answer (score 10):

You defined the route with `POST`, but you use `PATCH` in the form.

Comment: can you explain a little more? I am having a similar problem.

Comment: @TallPaul you probably copy-pasted the new form, like me. The action should be `:update`, not `:create`. Simple mistake.